# RecyclerView nullpointException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm getting this null point exception every time I try to call `recyclerView` inside a fragment.

As you can see in my code below that I have declared my layout manager. I tried declaring the `recyclerView` and `layoutManager` inside the `onViewCreated` and `onCreateView` but still the same error.

These fragments are inside a `viewPager` then each fragment contains `SwipeRefreshLayout`in them. I have 3 fragment all containing recyclerView if I will only use one the error is not showing.

```
private RecyclerView post;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

public NearByFragment(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_by, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    post = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lvPost);
    post.setHasFixedSize(true);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    post.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    post.setOnScrollListener(new ScrollListener());
    refreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.swipe_layout);
    refreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW);
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your R.id.lvPost is in R.layout.fragment_near_by. You should do it:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_by, container, false);
    post = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvPost);
    return view;
}
```